# Time Limit on certain pages in app - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, timer, countdown

I am trying to make a "news feed" type app, with messaging and other features. However, I am trying to make it so that you are **only able to scroll on the feed page for 20 minutes every hour** and once the time is up, the **page is "locked"**. There will be a **countdown on the top of the feed page**.

I have tried using a timer and lifecycle manager on the feed page, but I am struggling to understand how to go about this. The timer needs to pause when I switch to the messaging tab or settings tab and needs to upload and save when the app is closed, and then continue when the app is opened again.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Use DateTime. Log the DateTime when you open a screen widget and when you close it. Reset it every hour.

Comment: I will try this thank you. Would I have to log it every time they switch tab? and every time they close app etc.

Comment: Yeah, something like that. Personally, I'd just log the difference of the 'time in' and 'time out' of each tab, and also periodically check if the current tab has exceeded 20 min.